# Barras empilhadas Plotly Pandas

Tags: pandas, plotly

Tenho 3 dataframes, df1, df2 e df3. Cada um deles possui apenas uma coluna chamada "Avaliação", como a seguir:

```
df1
[Avaliação]
  Bom
  Regular
  Bom
  Bom
  
df2
[Avaliação]
  Ótimo
  Ótimo
  Ótimo
 Insuficiente
 Insuficiente
  Péssimo
  Péssimo
  Péssimo
  Péssimo

df3
[Avaliação]
  Bom
  Regular
  Ótimo
```

Estou tentando plotar um gráfico de barras empilhadas, semelhante a essa [imagem](https://www.delftstack.com/img/Matplotlib/Stack%20Bar%20plots%20in%20Matplotlib.png?ezimgfmt=rs:828x644/rscb5/ng:webp/ngcb5), onde a contagem de cada elemento na coluna "Avaliação" seja representada por cada segmento de cada barra. No caso da figura, por exemplo, tomando-se como exemplo o dataframe "df2", eu teria no segmento verde o somatório das avaliações "Ótimo"; no segmento amarelo  o somatório das avaliações "Insuficiente"  e no segmento vermelho o somatório das avaliações "Péssimo". Não estou acertando usando o exemplo da figura. Adaptei para o seguinte código:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1=df1.Avaliacao
data2=df2.Avaliacao
data3=df3.Avaliacao

count_data1=df1.Avaliacao.value_counts()
count_data2=df2.Avaliacao.value_counts()
count_data3=df3.Avaliacao.value_counts()

plt.figure(figsize=(9,7))
plt.bar(count_data1,data1,color="green",label="Python")
plt.bar(count_data2,data2,color="yellow",label="JavaScript")
plt.bar(count_data3,data3,color="red",bottom=np.array(data3)+np.array(data2),label="C++")

plt.legend(loc="lower left",bbox_to_anchor=(0.8,1.0))
plt.show()
```

Adaptei esse código [daqui](https://www.delftstack.com/pt/howto/matplotlib/stack-bar-plots-matplotlib/) (o mesmo que gera a figura acima). Tenho o erro

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (46,) (8,)
```

Nessa linha:

```
plt.bar(count_data3,data3,color="red",bottom=np.array(data3)+np.array(data2),label="C++")
```